# Maven task to update xml tag value

Tags: maven

I have a geronimo-web.xml file in my project

now what I wanted to achive is to update "value" of  with the ${project.version}.

I have tried maven antrun pligin like this:

It works but it updating the tag itself in the xml file from dep:version --> ${project.version}. But I need to update the value of "dep:version" from the xml file.

ANy idea ?

Comment: Could you be more clear about how your xml file looks like and what exactly do you want to replace?

Comment: @user3877467 I have difficulties understanding your english but i guess that maven replacer plugin might be good choice for you (see my answer below). A more concrete answer might also be given to you if you share more concrete information - like relevant parts of your xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you go antrun? There is maven-replacer-plugin ( https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/ ) Try this configuration:

```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
       <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.3</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>prepare-package</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>replace</goal>
               </goals>                   
           </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
           <file>target/path/to/geronimo-web.xml</file>
           <replacements>
               <replacement>
                   <token>value</token>
                   <value>${project.version}</value>
               </replacement>         
           </replacements>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
```